# Why do Python's hash() values differ in length?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash

I wanted to mask out some of the bits of Python hashes and was surprised when I checked the lengths of different hashes.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof(hash(42))
14
>>> sys.getsizeof(hash("Hello World"))
16
>>> sys.getsizeof(hash("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit"))
18
```

Having a hash function returning fixed size hashes would make it easier to work with them on a bit level. Is there a reason for the variable length? Is there a guaranteed minimum length?

Comment: `hash` just returns an `int`, which can vary in size (due to Python's arbitrary integer precision) and will include overheads beyond the bits of the number itself. However, you can still do bitwise operations like masking on an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(2**10)
14
>>> sys.getsizeof(2**20)
16
>>> sys.getsizeof(2**30)
18
```

The return value of `hash` is limited to some small number of bits (probably 64), but the granularity of the size of an `int` is smaller than that, so depending on the exact hash value, the `sizeof` can vary.

As a comment already pointed out, this has no significance for bit fiddling. For the purpose of bitwise operators, (non-negative) numbers are padded with an unlimited number of zeros.

Comment: Great! I hoped for the return values of `hash()` being randomly distributed. But using the identity function for hashing integers makes sense.

Comment: Note that in this answer, I am not hashing integers, only taking the sizeof them. But yeah, hashes in (C)Python are quite predictable, since the hash table (dict) works rather well that way.